# Cannot renew ssl certificates, notAfter never changes

Tags: ssl

Last two days I have been trying to fix ssl certificate problem in our servers.

We have two servers A and B,
I was able to connect A to B but B changed ssl certificate. They shared this key and we imported that one but when I try to connect B I am getting

```
$  openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect B:443
verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
notAfter=Sep 17 12:00:00 2021 GMT
```

So this is still old. Then I try to understand if I couldn't import new .crt file, and if it is sill old one.

```
$ openssl x509 -in B.crt -noout -dates
   notBefore=Aug  4 00:00:00 2021 GMT
   notAfter=Aug  4 23:59:59 2022 GMT
```

No, as you see certificate is new and valid. So I tried to use it to test connection to B.

```
$ openssl s_client  -connect B:443 -CAfile B.crt
```

But it still returns

```
 verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
 notAfter=Sep 17 12:00:00 2021 GMT
```

What should I do now?

Comment: Did you restart the service after replacing the certificate files?

Comment: Do you mean openssl ? I didn't restart anything, even I use -CAfile, there is two different result. When I check validity from .crt file, then it seems valid. But when I try to connect this valid crt file, it returns as it never use .crt file.

Comment: After replacing a certificate file you need to restart or reload the services that use it, so they can load the new certificate.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> $  openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect B:443
> verify error:num=10:certificate has expired
> notAfter=Sep 17 12:00:00 2021 GMT
> ```

So B sends an expired certificate. According to comments, they send a valid certificate when you use SNI to request the certificate for name B.

The solution is obviously to use SNI, as this is what B has tested and implemented.

Comment: But when I try the certificate that they send, such as openssl x509 -in B.crt -noout -dates I get right dates.

Comment: B is obviously not using that certificate as the dates doesn't match. When you connect to B, B sends a certificate that it uses to authenticate itself. What matters is the certificate B sends, not what you have stored locally.

Comment: I can see from browser that they are using this certificate, dates matches with browser.

Comment: So you're not running B? Contact whoever is running B.

Comment: Thanks, since they are able to connect with SNI such as openssl s_client -CApath /etc/ssl/certs/ -connect B:443 -servername B , they say problem is with our certificates. But when I check https://serverfault.com/questions/799345/openssl-returns-the-expired-certificate-while-browser-shows-the-correct-one post I think they need to alter some config files, what do you think?

Comment: Ok, so they obviously expect SNI. Have you *tried* with SNI? I can't quite get heads or tails of this question.

Comment: Hmm, yes I tried. I could get Verify return code: 0 (ok) with SNI $openssl s_client  -connect B:443 -servername B. Thanks, I will inform B and let them know the problem is in their side.

Comment: The problem is not on their side. They obviously expect you to use SNI, and you don't.

Comment: They removed sni control while binding certificate. Now it is working, thanks.